# Populate a "this.Controls[controlName]" comboBox with XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, combobox, xmlnodelist

Im using `this.Controls[controlName]` where `controlName` is the variable that represents my `comboBox`.

I have data in an `XmlNodeList`. It's just a set of single elements with one text node each.

I want to populate the `comboBox` with this data - it doesn't matter to me whether the data stays as an `XmlNodeList`, or if I convert it to a list, or some other idea...

The thing I need help with is hooking up a `comboBox` to some data when I can only access the `comboBox` through `this.Controls`.

I guess maybe I don't understand what `.DataBindings` wants and why I can't just treat my dynamically created `comboBox` name as if it were a hard coded name of a `comboBox` - in other words, I'm assuming there's not a way to access the data in my `this.Controls[controlName]` using `Items.Add`.

Any suggestions are appreciated, but they should be simpler than it would be to just write a switch for each possible `comboBox` name.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a control dynamically, it should be certain at that time whether this control is ComboBox or something else. Once you have defined control, you can add items dynamically from XmlNode by using Items.Add.

Comment: I didn't add it dynamically... It's already on the form. 

I have a function which I want to use to populate a comboBox from an xml file, based on the first argument to that function. So... something like this: 

`
private void doSettings(string settingType)
{
    string controlName = "cbo"+settingType;

    string fileNamePath = pathtofile + settingType + ".xml";

    //this.Controls[controlName]
    //Do more stuff here to get the data out of the xml file and bind it to the comboBox
};`

Sorry - I dont know how to use the formatting for comments.